# How can I remove " from my string..?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

My string has  " and I dont want " then what to do..?

My string is like : "Hey My name is Viper

I want remove " from string

How

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Are you writing Java? PHP? Excel?

Comment: http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/24886/calc-macro-to-replace-cell-content/

Comment: Menu `Edit` -> `Find & Replace...` - search for `"`, leave replace field empty -> Replace all.